# Function of tm repetitively crashes R

Tags: r, tm

I have this line I want to execute:

```
tdm_english <- DocumentTermMatrix(doc.corpus, list(dictionary = dictionary_english))
```

doc.corpus has length 191,000 and dictionary_english 48

I run the very same line on a corpus 3/4 the size of this one and all run smoothly in few minutes (probably non even 5 minutes).

Now the function crashes my MacBook pro. I run it twice and both times I had to force quit R & RStudio after more than one hour of computation.

Is there any way to optimize my call?

Comment: Please do not use the word 'crash' to describe a process that takes longer than you thought it might.

Comment: Not just longer... I can't stop it using the "stop" button.

Comment: That's a failure of the package author to periodically return focus to the console. I agree with @PaulHeimstra that you could be paging out to virtual memory. The manner in which this is done varies with OS. On a Mac you can run ActivityMonitor.app to check for this. And as always .... buy more memory; it's very cheap. (You can also search SO for advice on maximizing available memory. Clean restarts are the first strategy.)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I bypassed the problem by using `TermDocumentMatrix` instead of `DocumentTermMatrix` that apparently is more stable on big datasets.

**Update**: I made it work also with `DocumentTermMatrix`. As pointed out by DWin the problem seemed to be that `DocumentTermMatrix` was memory insatiable. I managed to restrain its appetite with vapply. I tested it on a 200k records and completed the job without paralysing the whole system.

```
tdm_english <- vapply(doc.corpus, DocumentTermMatrix, FUN.VALUE = numeric(1), list(dictionary = dictionary_english), USE.NAMES = FALSE)
```

Answer (score 0):

From your description is sounds like you are running out of memory. To check this, open Activity Monitor and start the R script. Than check the System Memory tab in Ac. Monitor and see how many Page Ins and Page Outs take place. If this number is significant, combined with a high memory usage of your R process, this indicates your computer is running out of memory, and is using hard drive space to make up for it. This is very slow.

The solution is to use a smaller dataset, process the data in chunks, find a setting of `DocumentTermMatrix` that limits memory usage, or get more RAM.

Comment: What about slicing the dataframe in two, processing each part separately and then rejoining them? Could solve the problem? Could it be easily done? How? (I saw the package plyr affirms to do it)

Comment: I don't have enough experience wtih `DocumentMatrix` to say if this is possible. You could give it a try though.